# Detecting server connection error (404 status) in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to detect connection errors to the server, so that I can display an appropriate message to the user.

When the back-end server (a Web API) is off, and I'm trying to access a method on this server by using `http.get` I expect to get a response with a 404 status, or some sort of a connection error. instead I'm getting

> "Response with status: 0 for URL: null"

which is not clear.
So how can I detect connection error instead?

This is the relevant code:

**Login Component:**

```
this.loginService.tryLogin(userName, password).subscribe(_loginStatus => {
  //Some operations
 },
 _err => this.errMsg = _err; // this.errMsg will be displayed to the user
);
```

**Login Service**

```
tryLogin(user: string, pwd: string): Observable<LoginStatus> {
 return this.http.get(this.serverUri + `Login/?username=${user}&password=${pwd}`)
   .map(response => response.json())
   .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
}

private handleError(error: any) {
  const err = (error.json() ? error.json() : error);
  console.log(err);
  return Observable.throw(err);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this? Ending single quote is missing after ${pwd}

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula oops, fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Http Interceptors` here . Using the new `HttpClientModule` Interceptors are easy in Angular.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){ // here you can even check for err.status == 404 | 401 etc
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err); // send data to service which will inform the component of the error and in turn the user
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Register this in Appmodule like

```
providers: [
        [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: 
              AngularInterceptor, multi: true } ]
    ],
```

For more info on Http Client and Interceptors check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)